# I'm having a visual bug with the underlines in Visual Studio Code and I can't a reference of it anywhere

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

The error shows with import issues, as far as I can recall. When there's an error, vscode should put an underline under the class I'm in need to import. The problem is that the underline appears for a fraction of a second, and then quickly moves to the left of the line of code. Clicking on this new underline doesn't give me any useful options.

Let us use for example the declaration of an instance of a class not yet imported.

Here's my error:

[image]

What can I do to fix this? It drives me crazy.

Comment: This should be the same issue as this one: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2127, which has been fixed. So hopefully this problem will be gone in the next extension update.

Comment: Amazing.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Clean Java Language Server Workspace` from Command Palette or install the extension [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) .

If neither works, please file a report in [vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues), where you should get more help.

Comment: I tried this but the problem keeps happening.

Comment: @ffyeins. This question should be fixed in next release. or you may try [vscode insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) temporarily.